# Angular ng-repeat doesn't update content within it once array is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat to loop through an array of tabs as follows:

```
 <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    {{tab.heading}}

     <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="closeAndOpenOtherTab(tab)">
          Close '{{tab.heading}}' and Open '{{stc.threeTabsRight(tab).heading}}'
     </a>
 </div>
```

I also allow the option to remove the tabs by splicing them out of the tabs array by clicking on one, my controller looks like this:

```
$scope.closeAndOpenOtherTab = function (tab:) {
   var myIndex = tabs.indexOf(tab);
   $scope.tabs.splice(myIndex,1);
  }
```

This all works fine, the tab is removed and so is the content of the tab, until I splice out the last tab in the array. When I do that, the tab itself is spliced but the content of the tab is not removed, it stays on the page. It looks as though nothing gets updated inside the ng-repeat once the array is empty. I tried $scope.apply() but there is already a digest cycle taking place.

Here is what it looks like at start, notice there is a tab and then its content titled "Tab 1" below it:

[image]

When I click through to remove all the tabs, and then remove the Tab 15, here is what it looks like, notice that the tabs are no longer present but "Tab 15" is still there as the content for that tab:

[image]

How can I remove that when the tab associated with that content is removed?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a plunkr link, with the minimum amount of code needed to recreate the issue?

Comment: use ng-if to remove when no itens to show. (in the same tag): <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-if="tabs.length">

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo it would be better to understand the issue then put a hack in to hide the element if the array is empty.

Comment: Try printing out the array right after you splice the last element, also you have a typo in the argument of the function; its function (tab) and not function (tab:)

Comment: Please be clarify how you're managing the string 'Tab n' under each tab.  Note, in JS strings are immutable so you have to actively re/set them.

Comment: Also see this example with the angular-material tabs: it works perfectly fine http://codepen.io/gustavogsimas/pen/xEEagK

Comment: Yea I have printed out the array after splicing the last one and its empty. But the content never gets updated (or cleared out). It looks like I'm doing it the exact same way as the angular-material tabs. I added the click event code that is triggering the closing of one tab and opening of another.

Comment: ng-if="tabs.length" as noted above did not work. I get the same result which is nothing gets updated inside the ng-repeat once the array is empty. It stays exactly as it was when the last tab was present.